# ggplot in python: plot size and color

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

Folks,

I'm trying to use ggplot in python.

```
from ggplot import *
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='price', fill='cut')) + geom_density(alpha=0.25) + facet_wrap("clarity")
```

Couple things I am trying to do:

1) I expected the color to be both filled and for the lines, but as you can see the color is all grey

2) I am trying to adjust the size of the plot. In R I would run this before the plot:

```
options(repr.plot.width=12, repr.plot.height=4)
```

However, that doesn't work here.

Does anyone know how I color in the distribution and also change the plot size?

Thank you. The current output is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Color**

Use `color` instead of fill.
e.g.;

```
from ggplot import *
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='price', color='cut')) + geom_density(alpha=0.25) + facet_wrap("clarity")
```

**Size**

A couple of ways to do this.

Easiest is with `ggsave` - look up the documentation.

Alternatively, use `theme` with `plot_margin` argument:

```
ggplot(...) ... + theme(plot_margin = dict(right = 12, top=8))
```

Or, use matplotlib settings:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = "11, 8"
ggplot(...) + ...
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Color helps for sure, the size needs a bit of tinkering with, but nonetheless that solves my problem. I am not worthy! I am not worthy! I am not worthy!

Comment: `mpl.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = "11, 8"` did not work for me. I work in jupyer notebook.

Comment: @MartaKaras I like Rodolfo's solution below, adding the figure size to the theme with plotnine/ggplot.  That works for me in Jupyter Notebook.  I assume you are already declaring the following for jupyter notebook: %matplotlib inline

Answer (score 25):

Use the most recent ggplot2 for Python: plotnine.

In order to reshape the plot size, use this theme parameter: figure_size(width, height). Width and height are in inches.

Refer to this library documentation: https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.themes.themeable.figure_size.html#plotnine.themes.themeable.figure_size

See the following example:

```
from plotnine import *

(ggplot(df) 
 + aes(x='column_X', y='column_Y', color = 'column_for_collor')    
 + geom_line()
 + theme(axis_text_x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
 + facet_wrap('~column_to_facet', ncol = 3)   # ncol to define 3 facets per line
 + theme(figure_size=(16, 8))  # here you define the plot size
)
```

Comment: You can also set the default figure size for all plots using the plotnine options: `plotnine.options.figure_size = (16, 8)`

Comment: I like to control the figure size in each plot, which give me more flexibility. But of course a well defined default is good.

Answer (score 3):

This is the top answer that comes up in Google when searching how to increase the size of `plotnine` plot. None of the answers worked for me but increasing the [figure size](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.themes.themeable.figure_size.html#plotnine.themes.themeable.figure_size) theme did:

```
from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import diamonds
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='price', color='cut')) + geom_density(alpha=0.25) + facet_wrap("clarity") + theme(figure_size = (10, 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, if you don't want to alter matplotlib's configuration:

```py
from ggplot import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

p = (ggplot(diamonds,
          aes(x='x', y='y', color='cut', fill='cut')) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_wrap(x='cut'))

# This command "renders" the figure and creates the attribute `fig` on the p object
p.make()

# Then you can alter its properties
p.fig.set_size_inches(15, 5, forward=True)
p.fig.set_dpi(100)
p.fig

# And display the final figure
plt.show()
```